# Can not please accept æ, ø, å

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is how I have two input fields where customers get to use these characters.

**Æ Ø Å**

The one place it gives me no problems at all but it somewhere it will not approve the characters I use.

Problemer are here:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Husk byen")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Du har glemt at skrive byen?", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-åA-Å]+$", ErrorMessage = "Husk det skal være byen")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Byen")]
    public string Byen
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

Thus, it works just fine here.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Husk Adresse")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Du har glemt at skrive adressen?", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-åA-Å]+$", ErrorMessage = "Husk det skal være Adresse")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Adresse")]
    public string Adresse
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

[See it image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCJXX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

**"^[a-åA-Å]+$"**

to

**"^[æøåÆØÅa-zA-Z]+$"**

Comment: Thanks for its help. i hop u will giv me a +1 for my question